# scipy.interpolate.pchip got error

Tags: scipy, interpolation

I am trying to run the code below:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 2.5]
xs = np.linspace(x[0],x[-1],100)
curve = interpolate.pchip(x,y)
ys = curve(xs)
dys = curve.derivative(xs)
pl.plot(xs,ys,label=u'pchip')
pl.plot(xs,dys,label=u'derivative')
pl.plot(x,y,'o')
pl.legend(loc='best')
pl.grid()
pl.margins(0.1,0.1)
pl.show()
```

but got an error like this:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-256eb8fb78c2> in <module>()
      4 curve = interpolate.pchip(x,y)
      5 ys = curve(xs)
----> 6 dys = curve.derivative(xs)#Construct a new piecewise polynomial 
representing the derivative.
      7 pl.plot(xs,ys,label=u'pchip')
      8 pl.plot(xs,dys,label=u'1 class diff')

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py in derivative(self, nu)
   1377 
   1378         """
-> 1379         if nu < 0:
   1380             return self.antiderivative(-nu)
   1381 

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The system I use is Windows+Python3.5+Anaconda+Jupyter notebook.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i interpret the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator), instead of doing:

```
dys = curve.derivative(xs)
```

you should do:

```
deriv = curve.derivative()
dys = deriv(xs)

# alternative
# dys = curve.derivative()(xs)
```

whiches gives:

[image]

Comment: Or `curve(xs, 1)` to evaluate the first derivatives in place.